# Laravel (Carbon) pulls wrong data from Database

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am pulling the last films added to the database with Laravel Carbon. he colum created_at is a timestamp. I added yesterday some more examples to test.

I use the following query:

```
    $current_month_film = DB::table('films')
        ->join('categories', 'films.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select('films.name', 'films.slug','films.created_at', 'films.category_id', 'categories.*')
        ->whereMonth('films.created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->month)
        ->orderBy('films.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

and I get the 35 files items addded in December, which is correct.

However the date is wrong, as you could see in the right side of the added screenshot, the Database is showing all dates in December, while the result of the query shows a random date in August.

I have not manipulated the data, looking into the variable **$current_month_film** I see it has wrong data:

```
                      [
                      {"name":"Wall Street",
                      "slug":"wall-street",
                      "created_at":"2016-08-31 14:00:00",
                      "category_id":6,
                      "id":6,
                      "category":"Drama",
                      "slug_category":"drama",
                      "image_category":"images\/category.jpg",
                      "updated_at":"2016-09-14 14:00:00"
                      },
                      {
                      "name":"Savage Grace",
                      "slug":"savage-grace",
                      "created_at":"2016-08-31 14:00:00",
                      "category_id":6,"id":6,
                      "category":"Drama",
                      "slug_category":"drama",
                      "image_category":"images\/category.jpg",
                      "updated_at":"2016-09-14 14:00:00"
                      },
```

Is not about format, but a total change of the value, that I do not know where come from.

Why is happening it and how could I read the right data from the database?

[image]

Comment: My guess would be you have a created_at column in your categories too and it gets pulled through categories.* and probably overrides the film one.

Comment: You are right! It is reading the created_at column from the category. I corrected it and now works perfect. By the way, how could show a better format like December 14, 2016?

Comment: When you call $model->created_at it is already an instance of Carbon so you could do $model->created_at->format('format string'). But that means you have to call that in your views every time. I usually make a model [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) called GetPrettyCreatedAtAttribute (which is then called $model->pretty_created_at) which outputs a pretty format and call this accessor in the views.

Comment: can you check created_at date of category table, i think it might be using category table's date